# Stil learning: "Why doesn't this work?" Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, still learning on codecademy, but for some reason, in every editor I tried, this code doesn't seem to work.

The latest editor I tried was [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

```
var cards = ["Diamond", "Spade", "Heart", "Club"];
var currentCard = "Heart";

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  console.log(cards[i]);
}

console.log("Found a Spade");
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code does work; it doesn't produce any errors. What are you expecting to happen that's not happening?

Comment: @ObsidianAge It doesn't do anything, that was my problem.

In the website I gave, there wasn't any result.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, even on JSFiddle.  You may be expecting to see output there, but the console (console.log) is part of your browser debugging tools, and not jsfiddle.

Open your development tools and look at the javascript console to see the output.  If you are not sure how to do that, comment back with what browser you are using, and someone can help you find out, or Google definitely can.